# Error while trying to mask a column in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I'm trying to mask some information in my table, when I use this :

```
ALTER TABLE Person
ALTER COLUMN DoB add masked with (Function = 'default()')
```

I get those two error :

> Incorrect syntax near the word 'masked'

and

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If the statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

That's literally the same code as the Microsoft documentation, but for some reason it doesn't work

If somebody could explain me what is the problem, that would help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mask a column using the `ALTER` statement the datatype of the column must be included in this statement.  The `ADD` keyword is also not necessary.  I don't know what the datatype of the `DoB` column from your example is but it will need to be changed as below.  From the name I'm guessing this is a datetime column, but if it's not the matching datatype will need to be substituted in.

```
ALTER TABLE Person ALTER COLUMN DoB DATETIME MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')
```

**Update:**
This error was a result of using SQL Server 2012 when this feature was [released in SQL Server 2016](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/01/25/use-dynamic-data-masking-to-obfuscate-your-sensitive-data/).

Comment: I tried it and i still got the same errors, i feel like i'm missing something really obvious, but i don't know what

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?  Data Masking was released in SQL Server 2016.  I just copied/pasted the statement above into a query window and ran this for a test table with the same name and a "DoB" column and there were no errors.

Comment: That's the problem then, I'm using the 2012 version. Well anyway, thanks for trying to help me

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with this to better explain the issue.